# How does a compiler detect memory corruption

Tags: c++, memory-management, compiler-errors

Recently, while working on a C++ project I forgot to re-initialize a counter variable, that was used to access a dynamically allocated array at run time.

As expected, the program crashed when executed, with errors along the lines of:

**"glibc detected malloc(): memory corruption"**

Now I know that new/malloc allocates some extra bytes of memory from heap for bookkeeping. However what intrigues me is the fact that the compiler detects that I've written some data where I shouldn't be. Any ideas how the compiler does so?

Comment: It isn't a compiler, but a libc implementation.

Comment: It writes the magic number 42 (the answer to life, universe, and everything) before and after the allocated memory block. Chances are that if something scribbles all over memory, it won't be the answer to life, universe, or everything, so that glibc can simply check that the answer to life, universe, and everything is still there where it should be, and if not, it must've been corrupted.

Comment: A *compiler* doesn't. This is a run-time error that is detected by the memory allocator inside the standard library implementation you use (`glibc`). And it usually does it by having a few extra bytes set to specific values before and after the allocated memory, and checking those on `free`.

Comment: Note that it may not detect the corruption at some circumstances. Don't expect it to happen every time.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Which is ironic given [this version of the question](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/831356-what-do-you-get-if-you-multiply-six-by-nine).

Answer (score 1):

It's the C library that is complaining to you; not the compiler. Specifically, it is the malloc implementation in the GNU C library.

Line 3738 is where it emits such an error.

https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/malloc.c.html

You would have to check the library source code to see what is happening. However, different libraries behave differently. They allocate memory differently and they may or may not do integrity checks.